# Is there a way to split a line by its order number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

What is the reason why I cannot access a specific line number in the already split string?

```
    a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLJMNOPRSTCUFSC"
    barcode = "2"
    import textwrap
            prazno = textwrap.fill(a,width=5)
            podeli = prazno.splitlines()
```

Here the output is correct:

```
print(podeli)
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLJMN
OPRST
CUFSC
```

However, when I want to split one of the lines e.g podeli[2] by 3 characters the python just ignores that and gives the same output like that split of podeli[2] (line 2) has not occured.

```
    if barcode[0] == '1':
        podeli[1] += ' MATA'
    elif barcode[0] == '2':
        podeli[1] += ' MATA'
        for podeli[2] in podeli:
            textwrap.fill(podeli[2], width=3)
            podeli[2].splitlines()
        podeli[2] += ' MATA'
```

The expected output would be:

```
ABCDE MATA
FGH MATA
IJ
KLJMN
OPRST
CUFSC
```

Is there a way to split the line by a certain length and its order number?
Thank you, guys!

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: What did you expect to happen with `for podeli[2] in podeli:`?

Comment: `(textwrap.fill(a), width=5))` you have uneven brackets here btw. Also I think it should look like this. `prazno = textwrap.fill(a,width=5)`

Comment: My expected output is:                                                                                            
ABCDEMATA
FGHMATA                                                                                                                             
IJ
KLJMN
OPRST
CUFSC

Comment: Your loop is overwriting the contents of `podeli[2]`, since you used that as the loop variable.  And since you aren't storing the result of the second `splitlines` anywhere, naturally you don't see the result.  What you want is to insert the new lines into the list, and that's a bit trickier.  Is this just for fixed locations, or are you doing this in a loop?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I expected that line 2 (FGHIJ) is split into two new lines. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It is being split into two lines, but you are throwing away the result of that split.  The `splitlines` call doesn't change the list.  It returns to you a NEW list, and it's your responsibility to patch that in to your list.  See my answer below.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you! It makes sense now. I am doing this in a loop, so I wanted to split the line only if the input barcode is == '2'.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your immediate problem by rebuilding the list, but I fear you have a more general problem that you haven't told us.

```
    if barcode[0] == '1':
        podeli[1] += ' MATA'
    elif barcode[0] == '2':
        podeli[1] += ' MATA'
        line2 = textwrap.fill(podeli[2], width=3).splitlines()
        podeli = podeli[0:2] + line2 + podeli[3:]
        podeli[2] += ' MATA'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should split a string you specified by a width of 3:

```
n = 3
[((podeli[2])[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(podeli[2]), n)]
```

Comment: `textwrap` will already do that.  Your comment doesn't address the problem of building a list.